# GTM - JS - parse error primary expression expected

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have an error each time on GTM : Error at line 10, character 32: Parse error primary expression expected, on this code :

```
<img src="https://secure.adnxs.com/px?id=829787&seg=8170611&order_id='transactionId'_'quantity'&value='transactionTotal'&t=2&other='name'" width="1" height="1" />

<!-- Google Code for CPA Achat TFC Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 850998157;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "_JJWCL6c2HEQjefklQM";
var google_conversion_value = <myvalue>;
var google_conversion_currency = "EUR";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Maybe it's the '_' starting the value for google_conversion_label  that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `<myvalue>` on the following line with the relevant value:

```
var google_conversion_value = <myvalue>;
```

More detail can be found [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3419241?hl=en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "type" attribute from your script blocks (`type="text/javascript"`), or GTM will assume the target document type is XHTML, and will encode the tag content.